# #34; instead of " being shown on websites

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I use Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.4.0 with MySQL 5.5.22.

Installed the same page on two of my servers and on one server instead of " there is a #34; displayed.

Apache, PHP and MySQL configs are the same. Why is this happening ?

Comment: The character set being used is different on the particular server.

Comment: Can you show the actual code producing this output? And the header data of the HTTP response of both servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was libxml2 issue. I've restored it from default CentOS repo and now it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Look your MYSQL var with :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
```

If something different between your two servers, modify your my.cnf file.

Comment: check apache's default charset in http.conf

Comment: i think it must have a default value like ISO-8859-1 or something like that. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-apache2-default-charset-in-ubuntu.html also check the browser's encoding too.

Comment: No, it's disabled on the other server and working ok. The text is coming from the database...